# How to show and access .bash_profile file from finder

Tags: bash, macos, unix

I was playing around with setting additional paths within ***.bash_profile***.  To see what would happen I did: `export PATH="/Users/neil/blah"` and purposefully did not include `$PATH` on the end of it.  Now of course my path is broken, so when I go into terminal it won't let me type anything.

Basically what I need to do is find a way to access my ***.bash_profile*** file to fix it in (finder preferably), all without using terminal.

Any suggestion on how I can find and modify this hidden file without using terminal?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manually type the path ~/.bash_profile into any text editor, or tell finder to show hidden files and navigate there. Also if terminal is having problems you should still be able to ctrl-c out of the messages and cd around the use vim to fix it.

Comment: I do want to mention that typing 'CMD + SHIFT + .' in finder will reveal the .bash_profile on the user directory and you can choose to edit from a text editor from there. Of course the permissions need to changed, but that can be done from finder also.

Answer (score 7):

`PATH` is only needed for lookups when you don't provide an absolute path. While

```
vi .bash_profile
```

might not work, because the shell doesn't know where `vi` is, the following would:

```
/usr/bin/vi .bash_profile
```

(Assuming the `vi` actually is in `/usr/bin/`).

Answer (score 0):

If you have admin privileges on the computer. Log in as a different user then rename or edit the .bash_profile with the bad PATH.